# How to log daily rotation in php?

Tags: php, logging

I am developing php applicaton and I want to log daily rotation in php.
I found *error_log* method but it does not log rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Apache **log4php**, that is same with log4j in java and it can produce daily rotation log.

Answer (score 2):

The default configuration file is /etc/logrotate.conf:

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly
# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4
# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create
# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress
# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d
# no packages own wtmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
monthly
create 0664 root utmp
rotate 1
}
```

Service or server specific configurations stored in /etc/logrotate.d directory, for example here is sample apache logrotate configuration file:

```
# cat /etc/logrotate.d/httpd
```

Output:

```
/var/log/httpd/*.log {
 weekly
 rotate 52
 compress
  missingok
  notifempty
  sharedscripts
  postrotate
      /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/httpd.pid 2>/dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true    endscript
}
```

try it may be helps you